# CSS - Vertically Align DIV content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically center some content via CSS. For the life of me, I cannot figure out the cause. Can someone tell me why the word "test" in the following HTML is always top-aligned no matter what I do?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
            <tr><td style='height:200px; width:300px; background-color:silver;'>
                <div style='height:100%; width:100%; background-color:gray; text-align:center;'>
                    <div style='vertical-align:middle;'>test</div>
                </div>
            </td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Why is it inside a table? You know tables are not meant for layout?

Answer (score 4):

A quick way to vertical align, like in your case, is to match the line-height with the height.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                <tr><td style='height:200px; line-height: 200px; width:300px; background-color:silver;'>
                        <div>
                            <div style="text-align: center">test</div>
                        </div>
                </td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `vertical-align` is only a CSS substitute to the `valign` attribute in `TD`, and therefore only works on `display: table-cell` elements (and no, the proper solution is not to change the displaymode of your `DIV`)

If you can set a fixed height to the div, you should be able to align it vertically with `margin: auto 0`

Answer (score 3):

This works well: http://www.andy-howard.com/verticalAndHorizontalAlignment/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `valign="middle"` to your `td` tag, like:

```
<td valign="middle" style='height:200px; width:300px; background-color:silver;'>
```

Comment: Probably this works in most browsers, but it is not standards-compliant. On the other hand, the use of tables isn't nice either.

Comment: The question asks how to vertically align `div` content, not `td` content.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting style='vertical-align:middle;' in the parent  element. Right now you are indeed telling the inner div to align the text to the middle, however you're not telling it to stretch and occupy the whole page. Basically you're ending up with a div element that's as small as the text.

You can use Firebug plugin in Firefox to debug this kind of CSS issue!

Answer (score -2):

try using line-height:100px