# vertically aligning inline-block elements

Tags: html, css

I was thinking that I could do like that:

```
 <div style='height:100px;vertical-align:middle;border:1px solid red;'>
    <div style='display:inline-block;'>hi there</div>
    <div style='display:inline-block;'>hi there</div>
  </div>
```

and the divs inside would get aligned vertically in the middle, but for some reason this doesn't work,
the only way I achieved this atm is doing this (using line-height = to height):

```
 <div style='height:100px;border:1px solid red;line-height:100px;'>
    <div style='display:inline-block;'>hi there</div>
    <div style='display:inline-block;'>hi there</div>
  </div>
```

what's the proper way of doing this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - Vertically Align DIV content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881245/css-vertically-align-div-content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good way to do it. You could alternatively add `display: table-cell` to the parent div, and in that case the vertical-align: middle would work -> http://tinkerbin.com/mxle0LH4 . Unfortunately the width gets cut out like this. The best way is, yes, to use the line-height. But set it on the parent element, not individually to the children -> http://tinkerbin.com/ssvg8yPX

Comment: tinkerbin is offline and it is not archived on archive.org, could you supply your answer inline?

Answer (score 1):

I use this

```
.inner { 
    display:        inline-block;
    padding-top:    40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}​
​
​<div style="border:1px solid red;">
    <div class="inner">hi there</div>
    <div class="inner">hi there</div>
</div>
​
```